# Start a javascript function only on a particular section

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm making a one page website which has two sections. I've added typewriter effect(something like this-
[codepen.io/danielgroen/pen/VeRPOq](https://codepen.io/danielgroen/pen/VeRPOq)
) to the second section of the website. However, this effect starts once the page is loaded. How to start the effect only when I scroll to the second section?

```
<section>
 <div> 
   <p> hi how are you? </p>
 </div>
</section>
<section>
<h1> Hallo, Wij zijn Occhio! </h1>
</section>
```

Comment: Listen to the document scroll event and check the position of your section

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can run your effect when you scroll the window and when you reach the second section

```
$(window).scroll(function() { 

      if ($(window).scrollTop() >  $("section:nth-of-type(2)").offset().top) {
             // run your effect here
      }

});
```

Comment: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/YQYGBN Like this? Sorry I'm a noob

Comment: @nafri i don't understand the question?

Comment: I added the above lines to the code but the animation stops working codepen.io/anon/pen/YQYGBN

Comment: @nafri look at this https://codepen.io/anon/pen/eRygbV.. scroll to the second section to see the effect

Comment: Thanks! But after the word 'amsterdam', the animation starts shivering due to some glitch